# finding a member property of an item in an array

Tags: c#

I've passed in the whole `sale` object into this function. In that `sale` object, there are many childs e.g. saleOrderItem, Payment, User...

sale.payment is an array

Question:
1) How do I get the `CodeNo` from the `sale.payment' object? (as payment is an array)
2) How to get the sale.payment.CourseByTutor.TutorId (as payment is an array)

```
  public static object GetSalesDataBySaleOrderID(SaleOrder sale)
        {
            return sale.saleOrderItem
                       .Where(s => s != null)
                       .Select(s => new { 
                                          Id = s.Id,
                                          Username = sale.User.GetSingleUserById(s.UserId).Name,
                                          Amount = s.Amount,
                                          CodeNo = s.SaleOrder.payment.First().CodeNo,
                                          TutorName = sale.User.GetSingleUserById(s.SaleOrder.payment.FirstOrDefault().CourseByTutor.TutorId).Name,
                                        })
                       .ToList();
        }
```

Here is how i bind the value to the object

```
 private void SaveValueToObject()
    {
        saleOrder.UserId = UserInfo.Id;
        saleOrder.Date = DateTime.Now;            

        for (int i = 0; i < dgSale.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            SaleOrderItem SaleItem = new SaleOrderItem();
            SaleItem.InventoryTypeId = Convert.ToInt32(dgSale.Rows[i].Cells["inventoryTypeId"].Value);
            SaleItem.InventoryOrCourseId = Convert.ToInt32(dgSale.Rows[i].Cells["inventoryId"].Value);
            SaleItem.Qty = Convert.ToInt32(dgSale.Rows[i].Cells["qty"].Value);
            SaleItem.Amount = Convert.ToDecimal(dgSale.Rows[i].Cells["total"].Value);
            SaleItem.UserId = Convert.ToInt32(dgSale.Rows[i].Cells["userId"].Value);
            SaleItem.Discount = Convert.ToDecimal(dgSale.Rows[i].Cells["discount"].Value);
            SaleItem.Remarks = (dgSale.Rows[i].Cells["remark"].Value == null) ? "" : dgSale.Rows[i].Cells["remark"].Value.ToString();
            SaleItem.Status = (int)SaleOrderStatus.Active;
            saleOrder.saleOrderItem[i] = SaleItem;                


            Payment p = new Payment();
            p.PayType = Convert.ToInt32(dgSale.Rows[i].Cells["payType"].Value);
            p.Code = (int)PaymentCode.RCT; // For Receipt prefix
            p.CodeNo = p.GetNewReceiptNo(p.Code); //Check if it is receipt, if yes, Get last Receipt No + 1
            p.UserId = (txtUserId.Text == string.Empty) ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(txtUserId.Text);
            p.Amount = Convert.ToDecimal(dgSale.Rows[i].Cells["total"].Value);
            p.Remark = (dgSale.Rows[i].Cells["remark"].Value == null) ? "" : dgSale.Rows[i].Cells["remark"].Value.ToString();
            p.PaymentMethodId = saleOrder.PaymentMethodId;
            p.DateIssue = saleOrder.Date;

            p.CourseByTutor.TutorId = Convert.ToInt32(dgSale.Rows[i].Cells["tutorId"].Value);


            saleOrder.payment[i] = p;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'get the CodeNo?'. Please give a clearer explanation of the problem in your question..

Comment: why dont you post the part of the code where you declared your SaleOrder class?

Comment: From the snippet above, you're already doing it.

Comment: hi all, i have updated my questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a workaround and solved this question by adding the desired properties e.g. TutorId in the sale.saleOrderItem class. Thus making the direct access to the sale.SaleOrderItem.TutorId.
This sound stupid but it works.